# Кастомизация/стилизация плеера Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, аудио

Всем привет! Помогите разобраться со стилизацией встроенного аудиоплеера Wordpress. 
[image: так он выглядит]

Сначала я, весь одетый в розовые очки, собирался прописать в у себя css стили Элементов, которые хотел исследовать в "ctrl+shift+I", однако не увидел там ничего, кроме тега "аудио", обёрнутого в "Фигуру".
[image: моя боль]

Поплакав, я нагуглил, что Wordpress использует плеер MediaElement, вполне себе кастомизируемый. Еле-еле я нашел в wp-includes внутренности этого плеера и с радостью кинулся потрошить его стили, меняя на свои.
Но в результате толку не было никакого. Далее, я решил оставить их в покое и просто подключить свои в functions.php. 
И снова ничего.
Потом, протерев глаза, я выяснил, что MediaElement по идее выглядит вообще иначе, вот так:
[image: MediaElement]
Соответственно, приходим к выводу, что не понятно совершенно ничего и пора звать на помощь.
Шо делать, уважаемые? Как разукрасить плеер по-моему?
Плагины все с ограниченным функционалом, платить не хочу, т.к. это учебный проект, гугл истёр до дыр.
 P.S. Умников, пишущих в стиле "включи мозги" и желающих самоутвердиться за счет моего невежества - вычислю по айпи и прокляну)

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то у вас отображается стандартный плеер, вид которого зависит от браузера. Навскидку, кастомизировать можно так же, как и всякие дефолтные селекты и чекбоксы: прячем дефолтный плеер, вместо него показываем свои элементы со стилями, а управляем воспроизведением через js код

Answer (score 0):

Забыл про  wp_head();
Отсюда и проблемы со стилями